# How do I manually _POST in Php?

Tags: php, post

I want to post "name" and "time" into a file in my website called "banned.txt"
I've already gotten this far but it wouldn't work, it just wouldn't insert anything in the file.

```
//Index.html
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Data</title>
        <h3>Data test</h3>
    </head>
    <body>
  </body>
    </html>
//file called "userInfo.php"
        <?php
           $name = $_POST['name'];
           $time = $_POST['time'];
           if($name!=NULL and $time != NULL){
               $myfile = fopen("banned.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
               $txt = "";
               fwrite($myfile, $txt);
               $txt = $name;
               fwrite($myfile, $txt);
               fclose($myfile);
               echo('Inserted',$name);
           }
           echo('Should be inserted');
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough information here to be sure, but I'll make a solid guess:  nothing was posted to this page.  Here's a way to know whether that's the problem:

```
<?php
    if (isset ($_POST['name']) )
        $name = $_POST['name']; 
    else 
        $name = 'Name not specified';

    if (isset ($_POST['time']) )
        $time = $_POST['time']; 
    else 
        $time = 'Time not specified';
```

When I put this instead of just `$name = $_POST['name']`, etc., the page loaded fine and banned.txt got "Name not specified" put into it.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for replying to my message. I actually got 'Time Not Specified' message into banned.txt for some odd reason. All I want is to use it like an API so I could submit the name and time via a link instead of a form. Please help, thanks again.

Comment: Can someone help me please?

Comment: Do you have a page with a form that submits names and times?  If not, that's what you need.  This page -- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp -- scroll down to the "submit" part -- shows how to use forms to submit things.

Comment: I don't want to use forms though. I just want to submit  it using a link

Comment: OK.  In that case, use $_GET instead of $_POST.  See this link for a brief discussion of this:  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php .  However, be aware that embedding the info in a link makes it vulnerable to someone rewriting the URL parameters, so a hacker could get your script to ban other users!